# fread reading past the end of file

Tags: c, file, codeblocks, fread

I wrote some simple code to read the contents of a file in C and output it to the command line just to familiarise myself with Code::Blocks. I just copied this code out of another program that i wrote (which works completely fine).

I open the file, malloc enough memory to store the contents of the file and then read the contents of the file into that memory. When I print the contents of the file, I'm getting random junk on the end. I added some debug print statements to check the length of the file (which comes out at 15) and the length of the string I read the files contents into (which comes out at 22). I don't understand why the string I read the data into is longer than the file?

Any help is appreciated, code is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
//open a file for editing
FILE * inputFile = fopen("hexfile.txt", "rb");

//Measure the file and allocate memory
fseek(inputFile, 0, SEEK_END);
unsigned long fileSize = ftell(inputFile);
rewind(inputFile);
char *inputData = (char*)malloc(fileSize);

//Save the contents of the file to a variable
fread(inputData, sizeof(char), fileSize, inputFile);

printf("File Size: %lu \n", fileSize);
int length = strlen(inputData);
printf("String Length = %d \n", length);

printf("Contents of file: %s", inputData);

//Close files
fclose(inputFile);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you stick a null terminator (a '\0' character) on the end of the data read from the file?  It doesn't look like it.  You know that strings in C have to end with a null terminator.  `strlen` will keep counting, and `printf` will keep printing, until they find the '\0' character.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. That was my first thought as well but i added one in with strcat and it still printed out random junk after the file contents.

Comment: @lucasRHCP You can't add to a "string" with `strcat()` if it's not a null-terminated string to begin with...

Comment: `fread` doesn't create a string.  So you can't use string functions (like strcat and strlen and printf) which the results of fread.  You need to make it a string by putting a '\0' in the right position.

Comment: Also, you have made `inputData` only large enough to hold the contents of the file.  You need to malloc it 1 character larger than `fileSize`, in order to hold the extra '\0' you're going to put at the end.

Comment: So if I can't add in a '\0' with a string function like strcat(), how can I add it to the end of inputData?

Comment: when calling `fopen()` always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when calling `fseek()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: in C, when calling any of the heap allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc)` 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting the returned value just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.

Comment: the function: `rewind()`, originally written for tape files, does not indicate if it was successful or not.  Suggest using `fseek( inputFile, 0, SEEK_START)` as that does return a status value

Comment: the function `fread()` 1) does not NUL terminate the read in data 2) can stop inputting before the requested number of bytes are read 3) does return a status that either indicates an error or indicates the number of bytes read.  Strongly suggest using something like: `ssize_t byteCount = fread(....);`  Then inputData[bytesRead] = '\0';`  To properly terminate the input data.

Comment: regarding: `int length = strlen(inputData);`  will return the offset to some 'random' byte (the first byte that it encounters that contains '\0'  Which is undefined behavior  and can lead to a seg fault event.   Note: the function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t` NOT an `int`

Comment: when calling `fread()`, always compare the third parameter with the value returned.   If those numbers are not the same, then loop, trying to read the rest of the input and appending to the bytes already read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  program is  almost correct.  To  have a  valid string,  it must  be
terminated  in  `'\0'`.  If  your  file doesn't  have  a  null  byte  by
coincidence, then your data has no end when read as a string.

To fix this just add one more  space when allocating memory, and set the
last byte to null:

```
char *inputData = (char*)malloc(fileSize+1);
/* ... */
inputData[fileSize] = '\0';
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it!